# Creating user in gerrit through ssh

Tags: api, ssh, docker, gerrit

I am running gerrit on dockers successfully until now. The next step I want to achieve is is as follows:

I have a service running and if the the service passes I want to to review the code as +1 and 0 if it fails. But to review code I need a user, for this I need to create a user account once the gerrit instance is launched, then add this user to the reviewer list for that project, then make this user review the code based on whether the service passes or not.

I am able to review the code using the below command:

```
ssh -p 29418 host_ip gerrit review --code-review +2 commit_id
```

But I'm not able to create a user and add the user to the list of reviewers for that project. I am not getting any errors but am not able to find out whether the command worked or not as I'm not able to find any new users added. I used the below command:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_watcher.pub | ssh -p 29418 host_ip gerrit create-account --ssh-key - watcher
```

My gerrit instance is LDAP configured. Am I going in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to create the user. I was not mentioning the group to which the user should be added it.

Comment: Can you add the command that worked for you, please? This might help other users that have the same issue.